# How to use custom LWC lightning component in lightning-datatable

Tags: lightning, javascript, lightning-experience, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

If we want to have custom lightning component in LWC lightning-datatable, for example Upload file for each of the records, how can we do that?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Step 1 : create custom component as follows.**

pocCustomComp.html :

```
<template>
    <div>
        Id: {recordId}
    </div>
    <lightning-file-upload label="Upload"
                           name="fileUploader"
                           accept={acceptedFormats}
                           record-id={recordId}
                           onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished}>
    </lightning-file-upload>
</template>
```

and its JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

export default class PocCustomComp extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @api acceptedFormats;
    handleUploadFinished() {
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('uploadfinished', {
            composed: true,
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true,
            detail: {
                data: { name: 'some data', recordId: this.recordId }
            }
        }));
        this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Completed',
            message: 'File has been uploaded',
        }));
    }
}
```

**Step 2 : Create a new component which extends datatable**

pocLightningDatatable.js:

```
import LightningDatatable from 'lightning/datatable';
import pocFileUpload from './pocFileUpload.html';

export default class PocLightningDatatable extends LightningDatatable {
    static customTypes = {
        fileUpload: {
            template: pocFileUpload,
            typeAttributes: ['acceptedFormats'],
        }
    };
}
```

Here we are defining custom data types – fileUpload. Also do you notice that we are importing pocFileUpload template? You need to create pocFileUpload.html in the same folder as pocLightningDatatable

[image]

pocFileUpload.html – you have to use the custom component that we created before.

```
<template>
    <c-poc-custom-comp record-id={value}
                       accepted-formats={typeAttributes.acceptedFormats}>
    </c-poc-custom-comp>
</template>
```

Observe the usage of `value` here, it is automatically passed as the value for the fieldName we define in `columns`.

**Step 3 : We can use the component (that extended datatable) where-ever we want**

```
<template>
    <c-poc-lightning-datatable key-field="id"
                data={data}
                columns={columns}
                onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished}
                hide-checkbox-column>
    </c-poc-lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

And the javascript which uses custom datatype:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import findAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/poc.findAccounts';

export default class Poc extends LightningElement {
    @track data = [];
    connectedCallback() {
        this.columns = [
            { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name' },
            { label: 'Account Number', fieldName: 'AccountNumber' },
            { label: 'Upload', type: 'fileUpload', fieldName: 'Id', typeAttributes: { acceptedFormats: '.jpg,.jpeg,.pdf,.png' } }
        ];
        findAccounts().then(res => { this.data = res; }).catch(err => console.error(err));
    }
    handleUploadFinished(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        console.log('data => ', JSON.stringify(event.detail.data));
    }
}
```

Note:  pocLightningDatatable.html will not have anything in it.

Apex class:

```
public without sharing class poc {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Account> findAccounts() {
        return [SELECT Name, AccountNumber from Account Limit 10];
    }

}
```

Reference: https://salesforcesas.home.blog/2019/07/26/using-custom-lwc-components-in-lightning-datatable/

[image]

Comment: I realize you are trying to provide an outline of how to make this work, but you should post fully working code - I can see that the PoC component won't compile as the JS is missing the required imports (at the very least). It would be better to provide working code to help people who try to take what you have shown to try it out...

Comment: Why do you use a new template and not the "standard" html file for the component?