# Lightning Datatable Picklist and Lookup Work Around

Tags: lightning, picklist, datatable, lightning-datatable, js-controller

I am aware that `lightning:datatable` does not support picklists.

The approved attributes are:

- action
- boolean
- button
- button-icon
- currency
- date
- date-local
- email
- location
- number
- percent
- phone
- text
- url

With that said, I have a need for a picklist value to be visible and editable in my datatable (as I am sure many other people have run into). My question is - has anyone found a good workaround for this blocker yet?

My workaround thought is to use the action button and have a drop down of either hardcoded values or queried values. I am not entirely sure if this is possible as I don't see in the documentation any where that you can define a "default" value like you can with lightning attributes.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

```
({
    doInit: function (component , event, helper) {
    component.set('v.columns', [
        {label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text', editable: true, typeAttributes: { required: false }},
        {label: 'Owner Name', fieldName: 'OwnerId.Name', type: 'lookup', editable: true, typeAttributes: { required: false }},
        {label: 'Type', fieldName: 'Type', type: 'action', editable: true, typeAttributes: {rowActions: actions } {defaultValues: 'value1', 'value2'}}, //PICKLIST
        {label: 'Tier', fieldName: 'Tier__c', type: 'action', editable: true, typeAttributes: {rowActions: actions }{defaultValues: 'value3', 'value4'}}, //PICKLIST
```

Answer (score 5):

In Aura lightning:datatable, it is not possible to have custom components but in LWC `lightning-datatable`, it is possible to have custom component in table columns. Below are the steps:

1. Create your custom component which has picklist.
2. Create another component which extends `LightningDatatable` and declare/refer to template.
3. Create the HTML template which uses the component in step:1 and should be in same folder as that of component in step:2 - this is same template which is referred in JS.
4. Use the new component of step:2 wherever you need and have the picklist datatype.
5. You also need a button to save the record(s). This `Save` button can be in column or as separate button above table which saves the records having picklist populated.

For detailed example of how to create this, you can refer to [How to use custom LWC lightning component in lightning-datatable](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/271111/how-to-use-custom-lwc-lightning-component-in-lightning-datatable)