# Hyperlink a part of Text in Data-table column

Tags: lightning-web-components, datatable, hyperlink

I am trying to emulate the below view in LWC. The description value "Click here for Email Template" should only be hyperlink not the entire value, the value is passed from the apex class. Can anyone help me out how to reach this requirement in LWC.

[image]

Comment: Did you try this? Where are you stuck? Can you show the code you tried?

Comment: {const columns = [
    {label: 'Time', fieldName: 'activityDateTime', type: 'date', 
    typeAttributes: {day: 'numeric', month: 'short', year: 'numeric', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', hour12: true}, 
        initialWidth: 175},
    {label: 'Event Type', fieldName: 'event_type', type: 'text', initialWidth: 175},
    {label: 'Description', fieldName: 'url', type: 'url', typeAttributes: {label: {fieldName: 'description'}, target: '_blank'}}
];} This makes the entire value hyperlink however I am looking only a part of it to be hyperlinked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom component and add it to the datatable via custom data type.  You will also have to create a component to extend the datatable.  This answer helps outline that [How to use custom LWC lightning component in lightning-datatable](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/271111/how-to-use-custom-lwc-lightning-component-in-lightning-datatable)

**Creating Custom Data Types**
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation