# LightningDatatable with custom attribute types

Tags: lightning-web-components

I followed this tutorial on how to create custom datatable columns (Custom Data Types): [(LWC) - Lightning Datatable: Custom Data Types](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/282682/lwc-lightning-datatable-custom-data-types)

I am trying to set up a custom picklist data type, but I am failing hard. I tried setting up at least something very basic with static values and later I'd try to connect to database.

I have three components (three folders). First for customTypeA (custom data type), second for customLightningDatable and third for myDataTable.

**CustomTypeA folder**

- customTypeA.html:

  ```
    <template>
    <div class="slds-p-horizontal_medium">
         <lightning-combobox name="types" label="Type" value={value} options={TypeOptions} onchange={handleTypeChange}> </lightning-combobox> 
    </div>
  ```
- customTypeA.js:

  ```
  import { 
        LightningElement,
        track,
        wire,
        api

    } from 'lwc';

    export default class customTypeA extends LightningElement {
        value = '';
        @track TypeOptions = [
            { label: 'New', value: 'new' },
            { label: 'In Progress', value: 'inProgress' },
            { label: 'Finished', value: 'finished' },
        ];

        handleTypeChange(event){
            this.value = event.target.value; 
            // Do Something.
        }
    }
  ```

**CustomLightningDatatable folder**

- customLightningDatatable.html:

  ```
       <template>  
        </template>
  ```
- customLightningDatatable.js:

  ```
            import LightningDatatable from 'lightning/datatable';
                import customTypeA from './customTypeA';
                export default class customLightningDatatable extends LightningDatatable {
                static customTypes = {
                    customTypeA: {
                        template: customTypeA
                    }
                  }
                }
  ```
- customTypeA.html:

  ```
           <template>
                <c-custom-type-a></c-custom-type-a>
              </template>
  ```

**myDataTable folder**

- myDataTable.html

  ```
    <template>
        <div class="slds-p-bottom_large slds-p-left_large" style="width:500px">
                <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
                <lightning-input id="inp1" type="number" label="Enter value" onchange={changeHeight}></lightning-input>
                <lightning-button
                    type="submit"
                    name="submit"
                    label="Submit"
                    onclick={changeHeight}
                >
                </lightning-button>
        </div>
        <div style="height: 300px;">
            <c-custom-lightning-datatable
                    key-field="id"
                    data={data}
                    columns={columns}>
            </c-custom-lightning-datatable>
        </div>    
    </template>
  ```
- mydatatable.js

  ```
    import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

    export default class myDataTable extends LightningElement {
        @track  height = 1;
        data = [];
        columns = [];
    }
  ```

[image: Folders]
[image: Folders]

I'm getting an error:

**Couldn't find the compiled component. If this component has a dependency on a component in the org or a component in a package in the org, test this component directly in the org.**

The error seems to be related to this code in customLightningDatatable.js, because it disappears if I remove it (but the component won't render):

```
import customTypeA from './customTypeA';
```

What is causing the error?

Comment: Did you created myDataTable inside customTypeA? 
As it appears in the snapshot, it is not invalid. You need to put it under `/lwc` or `any subfolder` which holds your components.

Comment: The myDataTable is in it's own component. Or I am not seeing what you are seeing? Thanks

Comment: Oh you posted two snapshots. I was on mobile & they were stacked & it it looked like you created myDataTable inside customTypeA. Can you see if changing the customType import from `import customTypeA from './customTypeA';` to `import customTypeA from './customTypeA.html';`

Comment: Thanks. You were right! I wonder why all the other tutorials had the import without the .html suffix.

Answer (score 1):

Fix:

```
   import customTypeA from './customTypeA.html';
```

Thanks to Sachin Hooda.