# How to add picklist options in a LWC Datatable when doing inline editing

Tags: lightning-web-components, picklist, lightning-datatable

I have created a LWC datatable. I have a picklist field (LeadSource)
set as "editable" true. But when trying to update the column it shows a text box and not the LeadSource options

[image]

is there a way to display the picklist options in the datatable as such:

[image]

lwc:

```
    import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import getContacts from '@salesforce/apex/ContactControllerv2.getContacts';


const COLUMNS = [
    { label: 'FirstName', fieldName: 'FirstName' },
    { label: 'LastName', fieldName: 'LastName' },
    { label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email', type: 'email' },
    {
        label: 'Lead Source', fieldName: 'Product', type: 'picklist', editable: true, typeAttributes: {
            // options: { fieldName: 'pickListOptions' },
            value: { fieldName: 'Product' }
        }
    }

];

export default class ContactListv2 extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;
    data = [];
    columns = COLUMNS;

     @wire(getContacts, { recordId : '$recordId' })
     wireContacts({ data, error }) {
        if(data) {
            let currentData = [];
            data.forEach((row) => {
                let rowData = {};
                rowData.FirstName = row.FirstName;
                rowData.LastName = row.LastName;
                rowData.Email = row.Email;
                rowData.LeadSource = row.LeadSource;

            });
            this.data = currentData;
            this.error = undefined;

        } else if(error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.data = undefined;
        }
     }
     

}
```

Comment: you'll need to do something like:  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/282682/lwc-lightning-datatable-custom-data-types

Comment: Check this link, it is explained here - https://techdicer.com/picklist-in-lwc-datatable-inline-edit/

Answer (score 3):

For now, the feature `Adding "picklist" as data type on lightning data table` is not supported.
This idea is logged at [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdcVyUAJ/add-picklist-as-data-type-on-lightningdatatable) but looks like Salesforce is not looking at it.

Comment: Please use Custom Data Types for Lightning data table