# How to show multiple links (comma separated) in one cell of Lightning Datatable

Tags: lightning, lightning-datatable

Is it possible to add multiple links to a single Lightning Datatable cell. For example, as in the screenshot.

[image: it should be something like this]

24 and 25 are different references that point to different records of the same object.

Now I use this code to display one link:

```
{label: 'Use Case', fieldName: 'Cases',  type: 'url', typeAttributes: {  label: { fieldName: 'CaseName' }, target: '_self' }, sortable: true }
```

Comment: Out of the box: no. However, you could make a custom data type to support this use case. See for example [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/271112/2984).