# Displaying Euro currency in lightning-datatable properly

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, lightning-datatable

Salesforce junior here.

I am currently trying to display some price information in a lightning-datatable.

However, the result is formatted like it's seen in the US, while I want it the amount of money displayed like it's in Europe. For example, as seen in the pic below, the first value in the first row should be 10.71 € instead of €10.71.

are there attributes that I can use to change the format?

Thanks in Advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As menntioned in documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation)

> lightning-datatable displays a currency using
> *lightning-formatted-number*.
> See Displaying Currency and Percentages.

And we do NOT have such attribute in [lightning-formatted-number](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-number/example)

However you can always create your **own data type** ,
where you can display the **Currency Symbol** as you want.

> The lightning-datatable component formats data based on the type you specify for the column.
> Before you create your own data type, check the standard data types to see if one meets your requirements. You can use type attributes to customize the output for many types.

Here some links which will help you with it :

[Create a Custom Data Type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_table_custom_types)
[How to use custom LWC lightning component in lightning-datatable](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/271111/how-to-use-custom-lwc-lightning-component-in-lightning-datatable)
[Display Custom Data Type in Salesforce lightning-datatable](https://varasi.com/development-and-admin/display-custom-data-type-in-salesforce-lightning-datatable/)